# ASP.NET MVC inline Razor variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In pre-Razor MVC I could write this in a view:

```
<span>I want to write in<%= myVariable %>side</span>
```

In Razor, of course I can't

```
<span>I want to write in@myVariableside</span>
```

bacause the template engine would look for the variable `@myVariableside`. How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First - have you tried it?

Secondly - if the interpreter has issues - you can try `@(myVariableside)`.

Equally if the variable name you're talking about is `@name` - then once you're inside the parentheses everything's fine, because the interpreter knows it's parsing C#/VB: `@(@myVariableside)`

Answer (score 19):

You can use `<span>I want to write in@(myVariable)side</span>`

Edit: Aww.. should have known better than to answer this question ^^

Comment: Damn. So it really was thinking thrice about writing a comment or making it an answer ^^

Comment: Hehe. This one's yours, but next will be mine ;)

Comment: Lol bring it on - you'll be soaring in those reputation leagues in no time :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
<span>I want to write in@{ @myVariable }side</span>
```

Comment: For me the curly braces do not work. The correct syntax seems to be using parentheses instead, as per the other responders.